# What is the more reasonable way to persistently store around 300 values with Appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, persistent-storage

With Axway Appcelerator one can persistently store data values as - among others - arrays and list of objects Ti.App.Properties:
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Lightweight+Persistence+with+the+Properties+API

Alternative, one can store those values also in a database.

I need to store around 200-300 objects/values with the structure word-translation-property1-property2. No complex queries are needed, just plain text.

**Should I use a database or can I store them as lightweight App Properties?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some basic testing (plain tab based app) and think AppProperties are indeed just fine.

The AppProperties list I stored had around 200 entries with the structure:

```
{original: "die Hauptstadt", translation: "la capitale", type: "noun", gcase: "0", color: "cccccc", gender: "F"}
```

App start up time seems to be not much different in the simulator (iOS) with around 30 ms.

The app size is also only negligibly bigger (the properties list with 200 elements showed around 40 KB more Data in Android's app settings).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties. That's likely the easiest.